# What is the best way to migrate from HDD to SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, data-transfer, ssd, migration, copy-paste

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I move my data to the new harddrive?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25202/how-can-i-move-my-data-to-the-new-harddrive)

I would like to purchase an SSD drive online to keep the cost low. What is the best method and software to use to transfer all my data from my current HDD drive to the new SSD drive? Below are the relevant parts of my System Report. Thanks, Chirag

```
Model Name: MacBook Pro
Model Identifier:   MacBookPro5,5
Processor Name: Intel Core 2 Duo
Processor Speed:    2.53 GHz
Number of Processors:   1
Total Number of Cores:  2
L2 Cache:   3 MB
Memory: 8 GB
Bus Speed:  1.07 GHz
Boot ROM Version:   MBP55.00AC.B03
```

Hard Drive

```
Model:  Hitachi HTS545025B9SA02                 
Capacity:   250.06 GB (250,059,350,016 bytes)
Revision:   PB2AC60Q
Native Command Queuing: Yes
Queue Depth:    32
Removable Media:    No
Detachable Drive:   No
BSD Name:   disk0
Rotational Rate:    5400
Medium Type:    Rotational
Partition Map Type: GPT (GUID Partition Table)
S.M.A.R.T. status:  Verified
Volumes:
disk0s1:
  Capacity: 209.7 MB (209,715,200 bytes)
  BSD Name: disk0s1
  Content:  EFI
Macintosh HD:
  Capacity: 249.2 GB (249,199,591,424 bytes)
  Available:    25.28 GB (25,280,106,496 bytes)
  Writable: Yes
  File System:  Journaled HFS+
  BSD Name: disk0s2
  Mount Point:  /
  Content:  Apple_HFS
Recovery HD:
 Capacity:  650 MB (650,002,432 bytes)
  BSD Name: disk0s3
  Content:  Apple_Boot
```